# Unit test function without return value

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have one function like this one:

```
def function(df, path_write):
    df['A'] = df['col1'] * df['col2']
    write(df, path)
```

The function is not that simple but the question is, how can i make a unit test if the function do not return any value??

If the function returns the new df it's simple, just make:

`assert_frame_equal` from the library `from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal` and mock the write method.

But without that return, how can i test the df line??

Comment: 1) Am I correct in assuming you meant to name the second parameter `path` (instead of `path_write`)? 2) In this example, is `write` supposed to write the dataframe to disk somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I can think of only two kinds of functions: Those that return a value and those that produce side-effects.

With the second kind, you typically don't want the side-effects to *actually* happen during testing. For example, if your function writes something to disk or sends some data to some API on the internet, you *usually* don't want it to actually do that during the test, you only want to ensure that it *attempts* to do the right thing.

To roll with the example of disk I/O as a side-effect: You would usually have some function that does the actual writing to the filesystem that the `function` under testing calls. Let's say it is named `write`. The typical apporach would be to mock that `write` function in your test. Then you would need to verify that that mocked `write` was called with the arguments you expected.

Say you have the following `code.py` for example:

```py
def write(thing: object, path: str) -> None:
    print("Some side effect like disk I/O...")


def function(thing: object, file_name: str) -> None:
    ...
    directory = "/tmp/"
    write(thing, path=directory + file_name)
```

To test `function`, I would suggest the following `test.py`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(code, "write")
    def test_function(self, mock_write: MagicMock) -> None:
        test_thing = object()
        test_file_name = "test.txt"
        self.assertIsNone(code.function(test_thing, test_file_name))
        mock_write.assert_called_once_with(
            test_thing,
            path="/tmp/" + test_file_name,
        )
```

Check out [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) for more details on mocking with the standard library. I would strongly advise to use the tools there and **not** do custom monkey-patching. The latter is certainly possible, but always carries the risk that you forget to revert the patched objects back to their original state after every test. That can break the entire rest of your test cases and depending on how you monkey-patched, the source of the resulting errors may become very hard to track down.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the mock for `write()` you can add assert statements to ensure the form of `df` is as you would expect. For example:

```py
def _mock_write(df, path):
    assert path == '<expected path value>'
    assert_frame_equal(df, <expected dataframe>)
```

So the full test case would be:

```py
def test_function(self, monkeypatch):
    # Define mock function
    def _mock_write(df, path):
        assert path == '<expected path value>'
        assert_frame_equal(df, <expected dataframe>)

    # Mock write function
    monkepyatch.setattr(<MyClass>, 'write', _mock_write)

    # Run function to enter mocked write function
    function(test_df, test_path_write)
```

N.B. This is assuming you are using `pytest` as your test runner which supports the set up and tear down of `monkeypatch`. Other answers show the usage for the standard `unittest` framework.

Comment: But with that function you do not test my function no? You just pass arguments but didn't call the function to test.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of the full test case

Comment: While the general approach of patching is correct, I think this is a very **dangerous** solution. (see my answer) There is rarely just _one_ test function. You should at least include code that restores the original `write` function immediately after that single test. The only safe way to ensure this is by wrapping the patching in a `try`-`finally`, and at that point the question arises: Why even bother writing custom monkey-patching logic, when a tried an tested module in the standard library does this (and a bunch of other things) for you?

Comment: I should have specified that under the `pytest` test runner, using `monkeypatch` is the supported method for mocking functionality, see docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/monkeypatch.html

Comment: Ah, that was not clear to me. In that case ignore my concerns.